# Regex to match a sentence which has specific words occurred n times in the sentence

Tags: regex

I want to match a sentence if that sentence has some specific words in it. So below is the piece of code MY SQL code from the PHP and i want to match the SQL sentence if it has 4 or more JOIN keywords in it. The starting of the match should start from the equal sign and the end should be the semicolon

Below is the PHP code , 
its not working for the below source file, its selects so many lines  actually i have only one query which has four joins

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT users.id, com.com, com.dt ".
"FROM com, users ".
"WHERE com.user_id = users.user_id ".
"LIMIT 10";

$query = "SELECT cd.id, sf.cap
   la.val as last_sort

FROM cd AS cd
JOIN ci AS ci
ON cd.id = ci.id
JOIN sf AS sf
ON ci.field_id = sf.f_id
JOIN ci as name
ON cd.ci = ln.c_id 
JOIN ca as ad 
ON cd.cid = ad.c_id
AND ln.fld = 7
  WHERE cd.progress = 1"
$result = mysql_quy($queryr));
?>
```

I tried with the regex below and it always stops at the last JOIN word .

```
=[[:space:]]*"[[:space:]]*SELECT[a-zA-Z0-9\"\,\.\= \n\_\*]+JOIN
```

But the problem with the above regex it selects the query which has 2 JOIN words queries as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `JOIN` you have to range `{4}` in your regex and end the regex with a `;`.

You can use this regex:

```
$re = '/=\s*"\s*SELECT\s+(?:[^;]+?JOIN){4}[^;]+?;/i';
```

i.e. match `=` surrounded by spaces then match `SELECT` followed by 1 or more spaces. 1 or more non-semi colon characters before `JOIN` and group it. `{4}` will match 4 of the grouped text and `[^;]+?;` will match till `;` is found.

Please note than `;` should not be in the quoted text.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM1mK0/9)

Comment: In the editor when i used the regex it properly selected , but when i used the same regex in the boost cpp , it has selected only the first line.Is there any thing missing for the new line when using in the boost regex engine?

Comment: I cannot test with boost but this regex will find a match across multiple lines also. May be boost regex has some flags

Comment: to http://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava  its not working for the below source file, its selects so many lines ,actually i have only one query which has four joins

<?php
$query = "SELECT users.id, com.com, com.dt ".
"FROM com, users ".
"WHERE com.user_id = users.user_id ".
"LIMIT 10";

$query = "SELECT cd.id, sf.cap
       la.val as last_sort

FROM cd AS cd
JOIN ci AS ci
  ON cd.id = ci.id
JOIN sf AS sf
  ON ci.field_id = sf.f_id
JOIN ci as name
  ON cd.ci = ln.c_id
  JOIN ca as ad 
  ON cd.cid = ad.c_id
  AND ln.fld = 7
WHERE cd.progress = 1"
$result = mysql_quy($queryr));
?>

Comment: Can you please  tell me which editor you are using to verify?

Comment: Did you check the link? I am testing regex on regex101 and you should also test there itself with your sample input.

Comment: I have tested the link with the below code , its selecting both the queries ,  actually if you see the code below 2nd SQL query has 4 joins not the 1st query.


    <?php
    $query = "SELECT users.id, com.com, com.dt ".
    "FROM com, users ".
    "WHERE com.user_id = users.user_id ".
   "LIMIT 10";

$query = "SELECT cd.id, sf.cap
       la.val as last_sort

FROM cd AS cd
JOIN ci AS ci
  ON cd.id = ci.id
JOIN sf AS sf
  ON ci.field_id = sf.f_id
JOIN ci as name
  ON cd.ci = ln.c_id
  JOIN ca as ad 
  ON cd.cid = ad.c_id
  AND ln.fld = 7
WHERE cd.progress = 1"
$result = mysql_query($query));
?>

Comment: I want to match the 2nd SELECT query which has the JOIN statements

Comment: it should not match the 1st query because it doesnt have JOIN,